# Adjust axes to plotted surface in Asymptote

Tags: automation, asymptote

I am plotting several parametric surfaces with Asymptote. When I change the parameters (`tyMax` in the MWE below), the value of the function can change significantly so I have to adjust the axes (`xmin,xmax,...,zmax` and `unitsize`) for each of them.

My goald is to adjust the axes automatically. What I thought of is simply to use the extremal values of `f(t.x,t.y)` for each surface, but I don't know how to achieve this.

How can I do that?

MWE (play with `tyMax`):

```
import graph3;

real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=2;
real zmin=-0.5, zmax=0.5;

limits((xmin,ymin,zmin),(xmax,ymax,zmax));

currentprojection=perspective(camera=(1.5,-2,1));

unitsize(2cm,2cm,2cm);

real X(pair t) { return cos(t.x+t.y);}
real Y(pair t) { return sin(t.x)*t.y;}
real Z(pair t) { return t.x**2+t.y;}

triple f(pair t) { return (X(t),Y(t),Z(t));}


real tyMax = 5;
surface s=surface(f,(0.,0),(2,tyMax), 60, 60, Spline);
draw(s,blue);

xaxis3(Label("$x_{n-1}$",MidPoint,align=Y-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
yaxis3(Label("$x_{n}$",MidPoint,align=X-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
zaxis3(Label("$\dot x_{n}$",EndPoint,align=X+Y),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
```

Illustration for `tyMax=5` and `tyMax=0.3` without changing the axis: you see that it needs adapting: while the first image is "OK", the second one is clearly not.

[image][image]

Note that the function are very simple in this MWE but in my use I cannot find closed-form expressions for the extrema.

Also note this question might be simply reformulated as "Find extrema of parametric function in `Asymptote`" but I wanted to give the context as there might be better solutions.

---

**Edit**
Added an illustration of the same problem with `orthographic` projection, with an even simpler surface.

Code:

```
import graph3;

real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=2;
real zmin=-0.5, zmax=0.5;

limits((xmin,ymin,zmin),(xmax,ymax,zmax));

currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(1.5,-2,2));

unitsize(2cm,2cm,2cm);

real param = 2;
real alpha = 4;
draw(surface((param,param,param)--(param**alpha,2*param,3*param)--(3*param,param,param)--cycle),blue
);

xaxis3(Label("$x$",MidPoint,align=Y-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",MidPoint,align=X-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",EndPoint,align=X-Y),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
```

With param=1, alpha=1:

[image]

With param=2, alpha=4:

[image]

I would like:

- the axes to be confined to the surface (i.e. if you reduce the box, you start cropping the surface)
- the ratio of the box to be always the same, let's say for example that the output should always be a cube.

Comment: The effect you want to get rid of is a consequence of the projection you are using. A quick fix would be to set the projection to `orthographic`.

Comment: @blaze I don't see what it has to do with the projection: depending on the value of the parameters I'm using, the blue surface can be either "very small" or "very large". I just want to adapt the axes to that (to keep consistent box ratio for example).

Comment: I see from your example images that your surface doesn't scale uniformly across all the axes, so I'm confused by "consistent box ratio". Furthermore, I'm confused with "for example". Do you know exactly what kind of result you want? Maybe give an example from the internet. I am not very knowledgeable of the mathematical details of the `perspective` view, but I think it is impossible to get all the axis parallel across the images, if that is what you mean by consistency. I do believe that the orthographic projection solves these issues in a quite elegant fashion.

Comment: What is possible is to determine the maximum possible size of your surface and use those `limits` to draw other surfaces. However since the surfaces may vary wildly that may not be a very elegant solution.

Comment: @blaze: If I know for each surface its (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax) then I can set the `limits` directly to these values, and adjust `unitsize` to maintain a cubic shape.

Comment: For a second I thought I understood what you were trying to accomplish (thanks for your explanations). But the changing of `unitsize` confuses me. Does changing `unitsize` break the consistency from picture to picture making them incomparable which is only worsened by the fact that you want them all to be cubes actually inviting the observer to compare them?

Comment: @blaze Oh, but I don't want to compare the pictures (like reporting values). In fact I just left the tick labels on the graph here to make it simpler to understand. In the end I just want to keep the axes (but no numbers) and the surface. So, let's say one surface is double of another one in the x-direction, then I would divide the first argument of `unitsize` by two. Do you follow? Sorry for apparently not being clear.

Comment: To get the cube: have you tried using `currentpicture.size3(5cm,5cm,5cm,keepAspect=true);` (with appropriate values for `x`,`y`,`z`)?

Comment: Another note: If `s` is a `surface` (parametric or otherwise), then `min(s)` is a triple `(xmin, ymin, zmin)`, and `max(s)` is similar.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Perfect! `min` and `max` do the trick. As for your first comment, the fact is that my code involves other elements to plot than the surface for which it is very handy to get the size of the surface. Feel free to post an answer, otherwise I'll do it.

Comment: I explored the `grid3` and `palette` modules in hope of finding out how they do the trick. Unfortunately, I was not able to figure it out as of reading the suggestion by @CharlesStaats. Thank you very much! A side question: Is there any documentation of this function or did you find about it by reading the source? What are the modules that implement most of the stuff other modules use (so I can focus on them when studying the source)? Also, should I delete my answer since it is not relevant anymore?

Comment: @blaze: I don't remember whether the function is documented, but in general, I've found that a lot of such useful functions are undocumented. This particular function is found in the `three` module, specifically in the file `three_surface.asy`. The modules that implement most of the stuff other modules use are `plain` (including the files `plain.asy`, `plain_*.asy`) and `three` (including the files `three.asy`, `three_*.asy`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `s` is a `surface` (parametric or otherwise), then `min(s)` is a triple `(xmin, ymin, zmin)`, and `max(s)` is similar. Thus, `box(min(s),max(s))` is the smallest three-dimensional box containing the surface (specified as a `path3[]`).